# Is it possible to put an external dependency to javac classpath in Bazel?

Tags: java, javac, bazel

Trying to find out if it's possible to use javac plugins in Bazel build system.
Input:

- there is a javac plugin jar in the Maven Central
- I want to configure Bazel in a way to have it on the javac classpath during compilation

I.e. I have the following in my *WORKSPACE* file:

```
maven_jar (
    name = "traute",
    artifact = "tech.harmonysoft:traute-javac:1.1.1"
)
```

and want to do something like below:

```
java_library (
    ...
    javacopts = ["-classpath @traute://jar", "-Xplugin:Traute"]
)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work - a jar reference is not substituted to an actual path.

[Bazel documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html) doesn't provide an answer as well, it just mentions that [only annotation processors are supported out of the box](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_plugin).

Is it the case that anybody more experienced with *Bazel* can hint me on the way to apply a javac plugin?

Answer (score 0):

AFK so low on links but take a look at using $(location expansion //target) and also add the target to the deps attribute (data attribute might be sufficient)